# Will Python execute finally block after receiving Ctrl+C

Tags: python, finally, ctrl

If you stop a python script with Ctrl+C, will it execute any finally blocks, or will it literally stop the script where it is?

Comment: It kills it where it is

Comment: I do not understand what your question is meaning.
I suggest you to read:
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
and
http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: run CTRL+C from MinGW / Windows it just kills the process, doesn't send any keyboard interrupt. But that's a special case.

Answer (score 29):

Well, the answer is mostly *it depends*. Here is what actually happens:

- Python executes code in a `try:... finally:` block
- a Ctrl-C is emitted and is translated in a KeyboardInterrupt Exception
- processing is interrupted and controls passes to the finally block

So at first sight, all works as expected. But...

When a user (not you, but others...) wants to interrupt a task he generally hits multiple times Ctrl-C. The first one will branch execution in the `finally` block. If another Ctrl-C occurs in the middle of the finally block because it contains *slow* operations like closing files, a new KeyboardInterrupt will be raised and nothing guarantees that the whole block will be executed, and you could have something like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line ..., in ...
    ...
KeyboardInterrupt

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line ..., in ...
    ...
  File "...", line ..., in ...
    ...
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: So how do we handle this case?

Comment: with statements and context managers perhaps? https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html. Or does the same issue apply?

Answer (score 10):

Yes, assuming a single Ctrl+C, at least under Linux it will. You can test it with the following Python 3 code:

```
import time

try:
    print('In try.')
    time.sleep(1000)
finally:
    print('  <-- Note the Ctrl+C.')
    for i in range(1, 6):
        print(f'Finishing up part {i} of 5.')
        time.sleep(.1)
```

Here is the output:

```
$ ./finally.py
In try.
^C  <-- Note the Ctrl+C.
Finishing up part 1 of 5.
Finishing up part 2 of 5.
Finishing up part 3 of 5.
Finishing up part 4 of 5.
Finishing up part 5 of 5.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./finally.py", line 7, in <module>
    time.sleep(1000)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will usually raise a KeyboardInterrupt exception, but remember that your application can be unexpectedly terminated at any time, so you shouldn't rely on that.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `finally` blocks will run following ctrl-c, as per other answers. However, if someone has overridden the default Python behaviour in an attempt to "avoid ugly KeyboardInterrupt tracebacks", then `finally` blocks will not run.

The way I've seen this done is with `signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)`. That will cause the application to exit immediately without any cleanup as soon as an interrupt is detected. As far as I can tell, this signal handler doesn't even bother to raise a `KeyboardInterrupt`. The standard behaviour can be restored by removing the above line or by adding `signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.default_int_handler)`.