# "Finally" block does not execute on stopping the debugger in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

When stopping the execution of the below code in VS Code, the `finally` block is not executing. How can I make this work?

```
try:
   while True:
     print('x')

finally:
   print('finally')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will Python execute finally block after receiving Ctrl+C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41280318/will-python-execute-finally-block-after-receiving-ctrlc)

Comment: It works fine for me on vscode, on pressing `Ctrl+C` once `finally` is printed and code stops

Comment: Not from keyboard interrupt. Stop from VS code directly.

Comment: @Killbill -How to understand "_Stop from VS code directly_"? When you run the code and click Ctrl+C, does the terminal display "finally"?

Comment: @JillCheng I assume OP means running the code using the VS Code debugger and [clicking on the Stop button on the debugger tools](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_debug-actions). With a basic launch.json and the posted sample code, clicking the stop button indeed does *not* print out "finally". It's not using Ctrl+C.

Comment: The issue is that the python debugger (debugpy) sends a SIGKILL signal to the process (with the running code), and SIGKILL cannot be caught and handled. So, killing inside the while loop is expected to not run the `finally` block.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53325394/2745495